# Bitwise AND Operation For Aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, aggregate-functions

My collection contains which checkboxes are checked, stored in a binary format. For example, if the first and the third checkboxes are checked, I store "1010" in binary.

```
{ "_id" : 1, choices : 3 } // 0011
{ "_id" : 2, choices : 5 } // 0101
{ "_id" : 3, choices : 3 } // 0011
{ "_id" : 4, choices : 4 } // 0100
```

Ideally, I would like to show, and possibly sort, how many 1s are in the same bit positions as {_id: 1}'s choices.

```
{ "_id" : 3, choices : 3, matches : 2 } // 0011
{ "_id" : 2, choices : 5, matches : 1 } // 0101
{ "_id" : 4, choices : 4, matches : 0 } // 0100
```

But I think it would be too complicated, so I just want to AND them, and send the score back.

```
{ "_id" : 2, choices : 5, and_op : 1 } // 0011 & 0101 = 01
{ "_id" : 3, choices : 3, and_op : 3 } // 0011 & 0011 = 11
{ "_id" : 4, choices : 4, and_op : 0 } // 0011 & 0100 = 00
```

My understand is to do and the bitwise AND operation, and group them as ***and_op***. However, the $bit operator seems to not be useful for aggregation, as it uses to perform a bitwise update of a field.

```
{ $bit: { <field>: { <and|or|xor>: <int> } } }
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "stored in binary format"? Is choices a string with the binary value, e.g. `0011` for the document with `_id` `1`?

Comment: choices is an Int32 type. 0011 is a representation of it.